# Is there any way to plot / re-express this `DifferenceRoot` expression?

Tags: plotting, difference-equations

I recently performed a calculation that output the result

```
    3*DifferenceRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {(-2 + \[FormalN])*\[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + (3 - 2*\[FormalN])*\[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] + 
     (-1 + \[FormalN])*\[FormalY][2 + \[FormalN]] == 0, \[FormalY][3] == 0, \[FormalY][4] == 1}]][1] - 
    3*DifferenceRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {(-2 + \[FormalN])*\[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + (3 - 2*\[FormalN])*\[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] + 
     (-1 + \[FormalN])*\[FormalY][2 + \[FormalN]] == 0, \[FormalY][3] == 0, \[FormalY][4] == 1}]][n]
```

Is there any way to visualise how this behaves graphically? Or any way to expend / reduce it to a more conventional expression?

I am struggling to understand how the function works...

Comment: You are not alone. I never understood `DifferenceRoot` when I first saw it, but again I never had to use it or deal with it.

Comment: Haha. Thanks for the reassurance @Nasser! I thiiiiink It's a kind of expression for the generating function of a sequence - but I really don't know. And a result, I find it impossible to work with :-(

Comment: **I find it impossible to work with** although I do not understand where it is useful myself since I do not use it, notice that help says `DifferenceRoot can be used like any other mathematical function.`  so may be try and see what happens if you do that. Also help says `FunctionExpand will attempt to convert DifferenceRoot functions in terms of special functions.` so may be this could be of use for what you are doing.

Comment: Sadly, `FunctionExpand` leaves the expression untouched, and `Table`, `ListPlot`, etc just return the original expression but listed however many times...